# Contenteditable issue. Do not pass through to the right

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Why when I tried to move between "item" when i press 'left arrow' on keyboard all is fine and caret pass through "item", but when I tried to press 'right arrow' on keyboard it does not work? Caret still on previous position and don't move.

When I previously press Ctrl key and then 'right arrow' it pass through double "item". And this is the only way to solve the issue at least somehow.

I also tried something like: "window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);"

But there is no helpfull info returned by this method. May be you know some other Window method or property that will help.

```js
$('#main').on('input', function() {
    $(this).contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType != 3 
            && !$(this).next('i.wrapper').length 
            && this.nodeName != "I") {
            $("<i class='wrapper'/>").insertAfter(this);
        }
    });
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
div.main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

div.main span {
    width:40px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

i.wrapper {
    font-style: normal;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="main" contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;item&nbsp;</span><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;item&nbsp;</span><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;item&nbsp;</span><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;item&nbsp;</span></div>
```

UPD. I have some contenteditable element where I add some text and non-editable elements. I need to have opportunity to navigate between this non-editable elements with the help of keyboard.

Comment: can you explain your use-case?

Comment: If you add `<span contenteditable="true"></span>` it will work, but you will have spaces :/

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon I update my post and answer your question.